# NullPointerException in javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet.addAttribute

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, addattribute

Has anyone ever seen an exception like this (with version 1.6.0_11 of the JVM)?:

```
ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(null:-1)
    at javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet.addAttribute(null:-1)
    at javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet.addAttributes(null:-1)
    at javax.swing.text.StyledEditorKit.createInputAttributes(null:-1)
    at javax.swing.text.StyledEditorKit$AttributeTracker.updateInputAttributes(null:-1)
    at javax.swing.text.StyledEditorKit$AttributeTracker.caretUpdate(null:-1)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.fireCaretUpdate(null:-1)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent$MutableCaretEvent.fire(null:-1)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent$MutableCaretEvent.mouseReleased(null:-1)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(null:-1)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(null:-1)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(null:-1)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(null:-1)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(null:-1)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(null:-1)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(null:-1)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(null:-1)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(null:-1)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(null:-1)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(null:-1)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(null:-1)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(null:-1)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(null:-1)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(null:-1)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(null:-1)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(null:-1)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(null:-1)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(null:-1)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(null:-1)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(null:-1)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(null:-1)
```

The JTextComponent was just being clicked on when this happened (it certainly doesn't happen every time you click on it).

I wish I could tell you an easy way to reproduce this, but I can’t.  It’s happening in a Java Swing application I maintain.  It happens infrequently and the application is quite complex.

I know it’s a bit of a long shot just showing this stack trace, but I thought I’d try.

Comment: Interesting, no source lines in the stacktrace. How and where are you executing it? What JVM are you using? At first glance this look like a concurrency issue. Is the app written with multithreading/threadsafety in mind?

Comment: I'm using version 1.6.0_11 of the JVM.

Comment: What were you doing on that TextComponent when this happened?  Can we see code where it gets set up?

Comment: The JTextComponent was just being clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're updating the document *only* on the Swing Event Dispatch Thread.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see from this, is that a "null" has been inserted as InputAttribute of the Element under the caret.

I mean, from checking sources of these classes, I think the problem occurs at this point:

```
javax.swing.text.StyledEditorKit.createInputAttributes(null:-1)
javax.swing.text.StyledEditorKit$AttributeTracker.updateInputAttributes(null:-1)
```

From the source, at this point the editor kit recovers the current `Element` from the `Document`.

*Excerpt from StyledEditorKit:*

```
Element run;
currentParagraph = doc.getParagraphElement(start);
if (currentParagraph.getStartOffset() == start || dot != mark) {
    // Get the attributes from the character at the selection
    // if in a different paragrah!
    run = doc.getCharacterElement(start);
}
else {
    run = doc.getCharacterElement(Math.max(start-1, 0));
}
if (run != currentRun) {
    currentRun = run;
    createInputAttributes(currentRun, getInputAttributes());
}
```

This `Element` is not null, but its list of attributes contains a null element, which is then used directly in the `addAttribute()` and `Hashtable.put()`, causing the NPE.

So in my opinion, the only place where something bad can happen is in the Document. Check if you are using a custom Document for this JTextComponent, and be sure to check what exactly is done inside.

Because from tracing the whole thing, it can only be a problem at this place. The Event processing and caret update doesn't have an impact in it, it's just a regular update. The part after is only consequence, using the object passed. So it seems like the key point is in the Document.

Comment: By the Document for the JTextComponent, do you mean the value of JTextComponent.model?  That happens to be an instance of javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument.

Comment: @Paul - Ok, then I have no idea. Check what is accessing/modifying this Document, maybe. Pity for my demonstration, it falls flat :)

Comment: After this line: 

     Document aDoc = c.getDocument();

aDoc is a javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument., So I guess it's not a custom document.

Comment: @Paul - I meant simply if it is only simply set there, or if somewhere in the program this Document is accessed, somehow, for example to set the style explicitly, etc. Maybe there could be a problem.

Comment: Yes, we are setting styles explicitly.

Comment: @Paul - then I would check in these methods, to find when you add a null attributes. (conditional breakpoint, maybe). Or simply protect adding the new attribute (but then you won't know the initial cause).